# Showing that a QBF in 3DNF form is in $NP^{NP}$

Tags: complexity-theory, oracles

Consider the problem of checking whether a quantified Boolean formula of the form
$∃X_1 . . . ∃X_n ∀Y_1 . . . ∀Y_m \phi$,
for $\phi$ in $3DNF$ over $X_1, . . . , X_n, Y_1, . . . , Y_m$, is true.

I'm trying to show that it's in $NP^{NP}$

My attempt (probably not correct, it's a guess):

Consider the following problem: $∀Y_1 . . . ∀Y_m \phi$ where $\phi$ is in $3DNF$. This is equivalent to solving a DNF Tautology problem, where $\phi \in DNF-TAUT \iff (not)\phi \in CNF-UNSAT$ (the problem  of given a CNF formula finding out if there's no satisfying assignments).

$CNF-UNSAT \in co-NP$ and co-NP problems can be simulated using NP oracles, so we can use an NP oracle to solve that part of the problem.

Then the $\exists$ parts is equivalent to finding a satisfiable formula. Since $SAT \in NP$, together, they can be simulated on an $NP^{NP}$ oracle.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How I'm meant to show that the problem is in $NP^{NP}$

Comment: As you already have a sketch of a proof, you should be more specific!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if my proof is correct given that I'm not sure when we'd make the oracle calls to solve the $\forall$ parts while solving an instance of SAT (Given that they're both together, and the $\exists$ parts and the $\forall$ parts aren't independent)